# Glassfish crash(stop) with no debugging information

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am runnning a glassfish 3.0.1, the server start up normally, but when i execute some webservice method the server crash(shutdown) without log or debug information. The files  server.log no have exception and jvm.log eihter. have i other log for debug error in glassfish?

Comment: Try running GlassFish on the command line, by executing `glassfish/bin/startserv` in a terminal in Unix/Linux or `glassfish\bin\startserv.bat` in a Windows command window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem increasing the -Xss memory in the virtual machine options.
-Xss256k to -Xss512k 
[image]