# Glassfish 4 server stops unexpectedly With no log

Tags: java, glassfish

i am using glassfish 4.1 build 13 on a cent OS 7 with 12G RAM and 2 core virtual machine. once in while ( no pattern ) glassfish stop working with no debugging log on server.log file. 
i start glassfish with these jvm options
-Xmx2048m
-Xms2048m
-server
-Xss512k
and my server have normal traffic not something that can not be handled
i have read these posts but they hadn't helped :

[Glassfish 4 server stops unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079951/glassfish-4-server-stops-unexpectedly)

[Glassfish crash(stop) with no debugging information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895424/glassfish-crashstop-with-no-debugging-information)

and i have to add i checked GC and jvm log for anything useful but there is nothing there also!!

Comment: Looks like something OS level, so check first that you dont' have any OOM killer running on your server and check Centos logs - there will be reason for java process termination.

Comment: Thank you! i did check that, most of the time OOM killer do that for resource problem. dose OOM killer log killing some process!?